Existence of functorial (K-)flat resolutions?
I am wondering about the following: Suppose $X$ is a reasonable scheme or stack with the resolution property.  (So, all quasi-coherent sheaves admit a surjection from a flat sheaf.)  Then I believe that all sheaves in the unbounded category of cochains $\operatorname{Ch}(X)=\operatorname{Ch}(\operatorname{QCoh}(X))$ admit a $K$-flat resolution, in the sense of Spaltenstein.
Is it the case, however, that $\operatorname{Ch}(X)$ admits functorial $K$-flat resolutions?
Though I'm open to any information in this regard, here I might specifically seek an endofunctor
\begin{equation}
T:\operatorname{Ch}(X)\to \operatorname{Ch}(X)
\end{equation}
which takes $K$-flat values and comes equipped with a natural transformation $\epsilon_M:T(M)\to M$ which is a quasi-isomorphism at all $M$.  Or, maybe more reasonably, I might seek such an endofunctor $T:\mathscr{K}(X)\to \mathscr{K}(X)$ and transformation at the level of the homotopy $\infty$-category.
In the presence of a suitable model structure I believe that such things would exist, but I cant find any specific information in this regard in the literature.

Another and more "modern" approach would be using the construction of the complete cotorsion pair ("a half of an abelian model structure") generated by a generating set of objects in a Grothendieck abelian category.
Let $F$ be a flat quasi-coherent sheaf that is a generator of $\operatorname{QCoh}(X)$, as in my previous answer.  Consider the Grothendieck abelian category $\operatorname{Ch}(X)=\operatorname{Ch}(\operatorname{QCoh}(X))$ of complexes in $\operatorname{QCoh}(X)$.  Denote by $S^\bullet$ the direct sum of all shifts of the one-term (stalk) complex $\dotsb\to0\to F\to0\to\dotsb$ and all shifts of the contractible two-term complex $\dotsb\to0\to F\overset{\mathrm{id}}\to F\to0\to\dotsb$.  Then $S^\bullet$ is a $K$-flat complex and a generator of $\operatorname{Ch}(X)$.
Using the small object argument (see, e.g., the paper Eklof, Trlifaj "How to make Ext vanish"), one can construct for any complex $A^\bullet\in\operatorname{Ch}(X)$ a surjective morphism of complexes $G^\bullet\to A^\bullet$ with the following properties.  The complex $G^\bullet$ is a transfinitely iterated extension of copies of the complex $S^\bullet$.  The kernel $K^\bullet$ of the morphism of complexes $G^\bullet\to A^\bullet$ has the property that
$$
 \operatorname{Ext}^1_{\operatorname{Ch}(X)}(S^\bullet,K^\bullet)=0.
$$
For any two complexes $C^\bullet$ and $D^\bullet$ in an abelian category $\mathsf{A}$, the group of all cochain homotopy classes of morphisms $C^\bullet\to D^\bullet[1]$ is naturally a subgroup of the group $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\operatorname{Ch}(\mathsf A)}(C^\bullet,D^\bullet)$.  Specifically, this is the subgroup formed by all the termwise (degreewise) split extensions.
In the situation at hand, it follows that all the maps of complexes $S^\bullet\to K^\bullet[-1]$ are homotopic to zero.  Since $F$ is a generator of $\operatorname{QCoh}(X)$, one easily concludes that the complex $K^\bullet$ is acyclic.  Thus $G^\bullet\to A^\bullet$ is a quasi-isomorphism.
On the other hand, the class of all $K$-flat complexes of flat quasi-coherent sheaves is closed under extensions and direct limits in $\operatorname{Ch}(X)$.  Hence it is also closed under transfinitely iterated extensions.  Therefore, the complex $G^\bullet$ is $K$-flat.
The small object argument is functorial.  So one can produce the termwise surjective morphism of complexes $G^\bullet\to A^\bullet$ as above in such a way that it depends functorially on a complex $A^\bullet$.

I haven't completely digested your answer here, but I think this is more along the lines that I was looking for.  (This appears to be a kind of "cell attaching" argument for the existence of desirable resolutions, in conjunction with a small objects argument for functoriality.)  In particular, if I'm in a setting where the category is generated by vector bundles (which occurs often enough), then can I expect to have functorial resolutions by vector bundles.  Is that correct?

@C00 Functorial resolutions by infinite-dimensional vector bundles, yes.  It will be not just direct sums, but transfinitely iterated extensions of your original generating vector bundles.

I see, fantastic.  Thanks for the additional context.

I'd guess that if $X$ is a reasonable scheme or stack, then $\operatorname{QCoh}(X)$ is, at least, a Grothendieck abelian category.  In particular, it has a generator $G$.
If $X$ has resolution property, then $G$ is a quotient sheaf of a flat quasi-coherent sheaf $F$.  So $F$ is a flat quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$ that is a generator of $\operatorname{QCoh}(X)$.
Now, for every quasi-coherent sheaf $M$ on $X$, there is a natural, functorial surjective morphism $F_M=F^{(\operatorname{Hom}(F,M))}\to M$ onto $M$ from the direct sum of copies of $F$ indexed over the set $\operatorname{Hom}(F,M)$ of all morphisms $F\to M$ in $\operatorname{QCoh}(X)$.  Notice that any direct sum of copies of $F$ is a flat quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$.  So we have a functorial surjection $F_M\to M$ onto every quasi-coherent sheaf $M$ from a flat quasi-coherent sheaf $F_M$ on $X$.
Using this construction of a functorial surjection onto an arbitrary quasi-coherent sheaf from a flat one, one can construct a functorial resolution of any quasi-coherent sheaf on $M$ by flat quasi-coherent sheaves.  Moreover, one can even construct a functorial resolution of any complex of quasi-coherent sheaves $M^\bullet$ concentrated in the cohomological degrees $\le0$ by a complex of flat quasi-coherent sheaves.
Now, when you are given an unbounded complex $A^\bullet$ of quasi-coherent sheaves on $X$, you should be able to apply the original Spaltenstein's construction in order to produce a $K$-flat complex of quasi-coherent sheaves mapping quasi-isomorphically to $A^\bullet$. See Spaltenstein's paper "Resolutions of unbounded complexes", Proposition 5.6.  The context in Spaltenstein is a bit different (sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-modules instead of quasi-coherent sheaves), but I think that, given a functorial surjection $F_M\to M$ as above, the same construction as in Spaltenstein should be applicable, functorially.

I see, thanks a lot.  I haven't look into the precise mechanics of Spaltenstein's argument, so I'll take a look at that.  And yes, absolutely, I do what QCoh(X) to be Grothendieck abelian.  So I'm happy to take that for granted.
